# Can ng generate application have its own package dependencies?

Tags: angular, typescript

My goal is to have a multiple Angular projects, each with its own package dependencies.

Reference:
https://angular.io/guide/file-structure#multiple-projects

Repository:
https://github.com/jasonrichdarmawan/angular-my-workspace-example/commits/main

What I've tried:

1. Run these commands

```
$ npx @angular/cli@13 new angular-my-workspace-example --no-create-application
$ npx ng generate application my-first-app (default project)
$ npx ng generate application login
```

2. add `login-lib` library by modifying file:

angular.json

```
    "login-lib": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "projects/login",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/login/src",
      "prefix": "lib",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:ng-packagr",
          "options": {
            "project": "projects/login/ng-package.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "tsConfig": "projects/login/tsconfig.app.json"
            },
            "development": {
              "tsConfig": "projects/login/tsconfig.app.json"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "projects/login/src/test.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/login/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "projects/login/karma.conf.js"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@@login": [
        "dist/login-lib",
      ],
    }
}
```

add `public-api.ts` to the `projects/login/src`.

```
export { LoginModule } from './app/feature/login/login.module';
```

add `ng-package.json` to the `projects/login`

```
{
    "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
    "dest": "../../dist/login-lib",
    "lib": {
      "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts"
    }
  }
```

add package.json to `/projects/login`

```
{
    "name": "login-lib",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "peerDependencies": {
      "@angular/common": "^13.3.0",
      "@angular/core": "^13.3.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "tslib": "^2.3.0"
    }
  }
```

3. integrate `my-first-app` with `login-lib`

run this command `ng build login-lib --watch`

modify the `app-routing-module.ts` in `projects/my-first-app/src/app`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import("@@login").then(m => m.LoginModule),
  }
];
```

run this command `npx ng serve` and visit `localhost:4200`, I can see `login works!`.

kill the `npx ng serve`.

5. Install the `@ng-select/ng-select` package to the `login` application.

```
$ cd projects/login
$ npm install @ng-select/ng-select
```

6. start `ng build login-lib --watch`

```
jason@Jasons-MacBook-Pro-2 angular-my-workspace-example % npx ng build login-lib --watch
Building Angular Package

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building entry point 'login-lib'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
✔ Compiling with Angular sources in Ivy full compilation mode.
✔ Writing FESM bundles
✔ Copying assets
⚠ Distributing npm packages with 'dependencies' is not recommended. Please consider adding @ng-select/ng-selectto 'peerDependencies' or remove it from 'dependencies'.
✖ Writing package manifest
ERROR: Dependency @ng-select/ng-select must be explicitly allowed using the "allowedNonPeerDependencies" option.

Compilation failed. Watching for file changes...
```

What I've tried:

1. move `dependencies` to `peerDependencies`, but since the `package.json` in the root folder do not have `@ng-select/ng-select`, I can't import it in the `projects/login` folder.
2. installing `@ng-select/ng-select` in the `package.json` of the root folder and change the key `dependencies` to `peerDependencies` in `package.json` of the `projects/login` does not work either.

```
../login/node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select/lib/ng-templates.directive.d.ts:10:90 - error TS2344: Type '{ ngItemLabel: { alias: "ngItemLabel"; required: false; }; escape: { alias: "escape"; required: false; }; }' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [key: string]: string; }'.
  Property '"ngItemLabel"' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type '{ alias: "ngItemLabel"; required: false; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.

10     static ɵdir: i0.ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration<NgItemLabelDirective, "[ngItemLabel]", never, { "ngItemLabel": { "alias": "ngItemLabel"; "required": false; }; "escape": { "alias": "escape"; "required": false; }; }, {}, never, never, false, never>;
                                                                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Compilation failed. Watching for file changes...
```